# height equalling the viewpoint minus the scrollbar height

Tags: html, css

```
.class-name {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

The CSS above will not exclude the height of the x-axis scrollbar when calculating the value of `100vh`.

What is the solution in order to get CSS to exclude the height of the scrollbar when computing the actual numeric value of `100vh`?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context where the class is inserted.

The class alone in a body... I imagine putting 0 margin for the body will be the solution.

Examples:

without margin 0

```css
body{
  /*margin:0;*/
}

.test{
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
    <div class="test"></div>
```

with margin 0

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

.test{
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: IT works in this particular case because the scrollbar is not part of the body but the parent HTML document.